# how to plot horizontal line connecting candle high low at all price levels in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I want to draw a horizontal line connecting candle highs & lows at all price level 
to identify demand supply zone and displaying a count of candles highs & low  connected by the horizontal line at all price levels.

I want to identify price levels which acted as support/ resistance earlier.

```
//@version=2
study("Horizontal line", overlay=true)
plot(high, trackprice=true, offset=-9999)
plot(high[1], trackprice=true, offset=-9999)
plot(high[2], trackprice=true, offset=-9999)
plot(high[20], trackprice=true, offset=-9999)
// trackprice=true plots horizontal line on high[1]
// offset=-9999 hides the plot
//plot(high, color=#FFFFFFFF) // forces to show study
```

using the above code I am able to plot horizontal line for single candle high only but the issue is:

how to draw horizontal line which connect at least 10 candles high or low withing specific given range for example in last 500 candles.

how to display the count of candles connected by the horizontal line at a specific price level?

please, help.